# Rails installation with MySQL2 failing on Mojave

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
OS: Mojave 10.14.2
Ruby v 2.6.0
Rails v 2.5.2
Mysql 8 Server (installed standalone, not through homebrew, and tested through phpmyadmin)
```

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
```

I did:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
bundle install --path .bundle
```

And I am receiving the following error message:

```
Fetching mysql2 0.5.2
Installing mysql2 0.5.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/test_guy/Dropbox/Development/Rails/TestAppMac/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/ext/mysql2
/Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190128-82406-1b5c8qc.rb extconf.rb --with-ldflags\=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\ --with-cppflags\=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
checking for rb_absint_size()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:782:in `try_func'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1069:in `block in have_func'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/test_guy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1068:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:25:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/test_guy/Dropbox/Development/Rails/TestAppMac/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/test_guy/Dropbox/Development/Rails/TestAppMac/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/test_guy/Dropbox/Development/Rails/TestAppMac/.bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the command line development tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

Make sure openssl is installed on Mac via Homebrew.

```
brew install openssl
```

Install mysql2 gem with the options.

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

---

ref: [Install mysql2 on MacOS Mojave](https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/ee3ac6957c2ba4f7d7d33a251d58b191)

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL is installed and running then run this command

```
gem update --system
```

After that try to

```
bundle install
```

This should fix your problem